# CSS scrolling challenging case

Tags: css, scroll

Not another CSS scrolling question. Yes, but believe me, I'm ok with all the usual cases, but this is driving me nuts. If you look at http://mailwarriors.co.uk/vocab/csstest.htm you'll see a bare-bones layout with a typical fixed-height header and footer, and the rest split into some percentage-sized areas. On the left, there's a fixed-width div containing two further divs, each 50% height, which are called Panel1 and Panel2. If your browser window is too small to show all their content, Panel 1 and Panel2 get vertical scrollbars. But here's the thing. You'll see that the scrollbars apply to the whole panel, including the little fixed height 'caption' and 'toolbar' divs at the top of each, while what's needed is to get the scrollbars only on the actual 'content' div of each panel. If there were just *one* panel, I'd know exactly how to do it. But with two of them as shown, I'm just not seeing it. Can anyone advise? Here's the HTML/CSS for the bare-bones page:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>title </title>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

html{overflow:hidden}
#header{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:84px;left:0;height:82px;padding:2px}
#menuctr{position:absolute;top:84px;bottom:16px;left:0;width:200px;border:solid 1px #000}
#panel1{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:auto}
#panel2{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:auto}

#main{position:absolute;top:84px;right:0;bottom:16px;left:204px;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainWrapper{position:absolute;top:84px;right:0px;bottom:16px;left:204px}
#mainTop{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:70%;}
#mainTopLeft{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;width:50%;height:100%}
#mainTopRight{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:50%;height:100%}
#mainTopRightTop{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:70%}
#mainTopRightBottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;height:30%}
#mainImage{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0px;left:0;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainBottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;height:30%;width:100%;overflow:auto}
#mainSubImage{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0;left:0;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainInformation{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0;bottom:0;left:0px;border:solid 1px #000; }

#footer{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;height:12px;padding:2px}

.caption{top:0;right:0;left:0;height:14px;border-bottom:solid 1px #000;font-weight:bold;padding:2px 1px 0 1px}
.toolbar{top:17px;right:0;left:0;height:16px;border-bottom:solid 1px #000;padding:2px}

     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        This is the title area
    </div>
    <div id="menuctr">
        <div id="panel1">
            <div class="caption">
                Panel 1 title
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar">
                [panel 1 toolbar]
            </div>
            <div>
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2">
            <div class="caption">
                Panel 2 caption
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar">
                [panel 2 toolbar]
            </div>
            <div >
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        This is the footer
    </div>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div id="mainTop">
            <div id="mainTopLeft">
                <div id="mainImage">
                    <div class="caption">
                        this is another caption
                    </div>
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        this is another toolbar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mainTopRight">
                <div id="mainTopRightTop">
                    <div id="mainSubImage">
                        <div class="caption">
                            Yet another caption
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar">
                            Yet another toolbar
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mainTopRightBottom">
                    <div id="mainInformation">
                        <div class="caption">
                            A caption again
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar">
                            A toolbar again
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainBottom">
            Some other stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks in advance for any leads.

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this in CSS

```
#panel1{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:hidden}
#panel1{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:hidden}
```

And add this

```
.inner {left:0;width:100%;overflow:auto; position:absolute;bottom:0;top:40px;}
```

Then add "inner" class to content div

```
<div id="panel1">
            <div class="caption">
                Panel 1 title
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar">
                [panel 1 toolbar]
            </div>
            <div class="inner">
                panel 1 content<br />
                .....
```

Checked just on Opera so just to be safe check on other browsers too

Comment: Yes, that's like Sajid's solution, althougth with IE at least, I seem to need the 'position:relative' for panel1 and panel2 to get it working. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the panel to be non-scrolling, and only scroll the content. Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>title </title>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

html{overflow:hidden}
#header{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:84px;left:0;height:82px;padding:2px}
#menuctr{position:absolute;top:84px;bottom:16px;left:0;width:200px;border:solid 1px #000}
#panel1{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
#panel2{height:50%;left:0;width:200px;overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
#panel1 .content, #panel2 .content { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 38px; bottom: 0; width: 100%; overflow: auto; }

#main{position:absolute;top:84px;right:0;bottom:16px;left:204px;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainWrapper{position:absolute;top:84px;right:0px;bottom:16px;left:204px}
#mainTop{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:70%;}
#mainTopLeft{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;width:50%;height:100%}
#mainTopRight{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:50%;height:100%}
#mainTopRightTop{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:70%}
#mainTopRightBottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;height:30%}
#mainImage{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0px;left:0;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainBottom{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;height:30%;width:100%;overflow:auto}
#mainSubImage{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0;left:0;border:solid 1px #000}
#mainInformation{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0;bottom:0;left:0px;border:solid 1px #000; }

#footer{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;height:12px;padding:2px}

.caption{top:0;right:0;left:0;height:14px;border-bottom:solid 1px #000;font-weight:bold;padding:2px 1px 0 1px}
.toolbar{top:17px;right:0;left:0;height:16px;border-bottom:solid 1px #000;padding:2px}

     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        This is the title area
    </div>
    <div id="menuctr">
        <div id="panel1">
            <div class="caption">
                Panel 1 title
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar">
                [panel 1 toolbar]
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
                panel 1 content<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2">
            <div class="caption">
                Panel 2 caption
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar">
                [panel 2 toolbar]
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
                panel 2 content<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        This is the footer
    </div>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div id="mainTop">
            <div id="mainTopLeft">
                <div id="mainImage">
                    <div class="caption">
                        this is another caption
                    </div>
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        this is another toolbar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mainTopRight">
                <div id="mainTopRightTop">
                    <div id="mainSubImage">
                        <div class="caption">
                            Yet another caption
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar">
                            Yet another toolbar
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mainTopRightBottom">
                    <div id="mainInformation">
                        <div class="caption">
                            A caption again
                        </div>
                        <div class="toolbar">
                            A toolbar again
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainBottom">
            Some other stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Test case here](http://jsbin.com/axabo5).

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. I thought I'd tried pretty much that, but I must have been going round in circles with it. Yours just works.